# Never getting past PumpMessages

Tags: winapi, python-3.x, win32com, win32gui

I'm writing a script that interacts through a program's WM_COPYDATA api, but am stuck on the PumpMessage functionality.

```
import win32con, win32api, win32gui
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes

FindWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW
SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW

class COPYDATASTRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwData', ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM),
        ('cbData', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('lpData', ctypes.c_char_p)
        #formally lpData is c_void_p, but we do it this way for convenience
]

PCOPYDATASTRUCT = ctypes.POINTER(COPYDATASTRUCT)

class Stickies:

    def __init__(self):
        message_map = {
            win32con.WM_COPYDATA: self.OnCopyData
        }
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map
        wc.lpszClassName = 'MyWindowClass'
        hinst = wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow (
            classAtom,
            "win32gui test",
            0,
            0, 
            0,
            win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, 
            win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0, 
            0,
            hinst, 
            None
        )
        self.send_message("api do register")

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        self.send_message("api do deregister")

    def send_message(self, msg):
        hwnd = FindWindow(None, "ZhornSoftwareStickiesMain")
        cds = COPYDATASTRUCT()
        cds.dwData = 0
        str = msg.encode("ascii")
        cds.cbData = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.create_string_buffer(str))
        cds.lpData = ctypes.c_char_p(str)
        SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_COPYDATA, self.hwnd, ctypes.byref(cds))

    def OnCopyData(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        pCDS = ctypes.cast(lparam, PCOPYDATASTRUCT)
        msg = pCDS.contents.lpData.decode("ascii", "ignore")

        if msg != None:
            print(msg)

        return 1

s = Stickies()
win32gui.PumpMessages()

# Never gets past previous line
print("Hello, world!")
```

In my code, I can successfully send and receive messages, but I'm not sure as to how I can allow my scripts to do other things.  My goal is use this as a base class, and then incorporate it into other scripts.

I'm not sure how to:

1. get past the pumpmessage() function
2. handle the messages outside of the class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PumpMessages implements a standard Windows message loop.  It loops and processes messages.  You wouldn't expect it to return until the thread receives a WM_QUIT message (typically when the main window is closed in a gui app).

Comment: @arx: Is there a better way to wait for messages then?  Unfortunately I'm really not finding a lot of information/examples online for this type of stuff in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`SendMessage` is synchronous.  Send `WM_COPYDATA` to the other application and your code will wait in a Windows-internal message loop until you get a reply.

This means that your code can respond to messages from the other application while it is waiting.  This might be needed if the protocol involves an exchange of messages.

You only need a message loop if you are responding to unsolicited messages.

I don't know exactly what you are doing, but most likely you can remove the call to `win32gui.PumpMessages` altogether.

Comment: This isn't right, or at least the terminology is off. `SendMessage(..., WM_COPYDATA, ...)` is indeed synchronous. But the call to `SendMessage` returns when the message has been processed. I don't think it's wise to say that "*your code will wait in a Windows-internal message loop until you get a reply*". What happens is that the calling process blocks until the receiving process has completed processing. That's not a message loop.

Comment: Now, there probably does need to be a message loop. Something has to dispatch incoming synchronous messages. Typically that is done as part of the message loop. It's done inside the call to `GetMessage`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you get a message in response to a SendMessage (something that happens very frequently) then how is it delivered?  I forget.  I think you're right that it isn't a message loop.  Perhaps the message is delivered direct to the window procedure.  Either way, it isn't going through *your* message loop.  If he is driving another app he won't get any unsolicited messages so why does he need a message loop?

Comment: It depends when the message comes back. Does it come back inside the call to `SendMessage`. Or does it come back after it has returned.

Comment: The question is unclear.  He's writing a script to drive another application so I'm assuming that the message protocol is straightforward and synchronous.  But, yes, we don't know that.

Comment: @arx: I'm not driving the application, I'm working with its api, which is called through send message. I need to be able to handle unsolicited messages.

Answer (score 0):

PumpMessages freezes the current thread. If you want to do something after PumpMessages, consider making a new thread and running that using the threading module:

```
import threading
import win32gui

def otherCodeToRun(x, y, z):
    print("Hello World!")

t = threading.Thread(target=otherCodeToRun, args=(x, y, z, )) // You can leave out args if you don't have any parameters.
t.start()

win32gui.PumpMessages()
```